# String matching in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array of strings. I want to compare with the string which I am getting from JSON. Comparision should be like this. 
For example:
If Account name in one string is Google and in other it is Google Inc, then since Google is part of the Google Inc company name, It should get matched. Otherwise not.

Code which I have written:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < accountCount; i++)
        {
             //// account is found in the array                
            name[i] = account.Entities[i].Attributes["name"].ToString();
            if (name[i] == message.Current.org_name)
            {
                flag = 1;
                c.CreateOpportunity(message);
                break;
            }
        }                
            //// account is not found in the array                 
        if (flag == 0)
        {
            c.CreateAccount(message);
            c.CreateOpportunity(message);
        }
```

Comment: [`String.IndexOf`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8b1470s.aspx) and [`String.Contains`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx) are your friends.

Comment: I suppose you want `if(name[i].Contains(mySearchString))`.

Comment: @HimBromBeere ya that is perfect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `Contains` function instead :

```
for (int i = 0; i < accountCount; i++)
{
    //// account is found in the array                
    name[i] = account.Entities[i].Attributes["name"].ToString();
    if (name[i].Contains(message.Current.org_name)
        || message.Current.org_name.Contains(name[i]))
    {
        flag = 1;
        break;
    }
}                
 //// account is not found in the array                 
if (flag == 0)
    c.CreateAccount(message);
c.CreateOpportunity(message);
```

Comment: I tried this. for example name[i]=Agniket and message.Current.org_name=Agni. It didn't work.

Comment: This is not possible, check debugging step by step, you must have another line error. `"Agniket".Contains("Agni")` is always `true`

Comment: actually It is like this:  name[i].Contains(message.Current.org_name)

Comment: Yes but you say `name[i]=Agniket` and `message.Current.org_name=Agni`. So `"Agniket".Contains("Agni")` must be true ! Check debugging step by step the value of your vars. Maybe you have a space or an escape char ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Contains` for a case sensitive search

or `IndexOf` to speficify more options with comparison criteria

However for the fun of it we can use `Any` on an array or list

*Note : none of the above check for null*

**Contains**

```
var org = message.Current.org_name;

var found = account.Entities.Any( // does any entity contain org ?
    x => x.Attributes["name"]     // Get Attribute
        .ToString()               // Convert it to string if needed
        .Contains(org));          

if (found)
{
    c.CreateAccount(message);
}

c.CreateOpportunity(message);
```

if you would like a case insensative search you can use `String.IndexOf`

**IndexOf**

```
var found = account.Entities.Any( // does any entity contain org ?
    x => x.Attributes["name"]     // Get Attribute
        .ToString()               // Convert it to string if needed
        .IndexOf(org, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0);
```

**References**

String.Contains -
[String.Contains Method (String)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dy85x1sa(v=vs.110).aspx)

String.IndexOf - 
[String.IndexOf Method (String, StringComparison)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224425(v=vs.110).aspx)

Coparison type - [StringComparison Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparison(v=vs.110).aspx)